# Selenium WA using Chromedriver cannot send Message

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I Have Problem with my Application that send message automatically using Selenium Chromedriver, When i start to search contact it's work but after i click contact name the chatbox on the right side is not visible. When i try debug using UI, and when i Click contact name there's Error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') at app.9bf7959578bdb7663582.js:89:314265 at t.getUserDesktopOs (app.9bf7959578bdb7663582.js:89:314352) at t.useWAWebDesktopUpsellPlatformAwarePermanentCTACheck (main.c9c2a96602ab6e225e24.js:5:181653) at t.ConversationHeader (main.c9c2a96602ab6e225e24.js:6:105562) at _o (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:62964) at wu (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:120158) at vl (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:109100) at pl (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:109028) at hl (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:108891) at nl (vendor1~app.7f14216f970118f62a35.js:30:105698)
```

Mycode doesn't have function toLowerCase. Is it effect from the update chromedriver 115? Oh and by the way, i already try to downgrade chrome and chromedriver version, but still cannot send message.

Solution for Selenium Chromedriver